# If $\sum c_n$ converges absolutely and $k_n$ is bounded, does $\sum c_nk_n$ converge absolutely?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, absolute-convergence

Suppose a series $\sum\limits c_n$ converges absolutely and a sequence $k_n$  is bounded. Will the sequence $\sum\limits c_nk_n$ converge absolutely?

Since $k_n$ is bounded there must exist an integer $M>0$ such that $\vert k_n \vert \leq M$. We then get $\vert \sum\limits c_n k_n \vert \leq \sum\limits \vert c_nk_n\vert \leq M\sum\limits \vert c_n \vert < M\epsilon$. Does this show that
$\sum\limits\vert c_nk_n\vert $ converges absolutely?

Comment: i think i should say $\lvert \sum\limits \vert c_nk_n\vert$ $\lvert $ also

Comment: Abel criterion does the trick.

Comment: Please don't deface your own question.

Comment: See also: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/85287/b-n-bounded-sum-a-n-converges-absolutely-then-sum-a-nb-n-also

Answer (score 1):

Yes, your proof is entirely correct, though I think you mean $c_n$ everywhere you have $a_n$. In fact, this is a special case of an inequality known as [Holder's Inequality](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Holder%27s_inequality), with $p = 1$ and $q = \infty$.

Answer (score 0):

Another proof uses
Cauchy's criterion:
A series
$\sum_j c_j$
converges if and only if,
for any $\epsilon > 0$,
there is a $N(\epsilon)$
such that
$|\sum_{j=m}^n c_j|
< \epsilon$
for all $N(\epsilon) < m < n$.
Since $|k_j| < M$,
$|\sum_{j=m}^n k_j c_j|
< M\epsilon$
for $N(\epsilon) < m < n$.

I would say this is enough,
but if you want get the bound to be
$\epsilon$ instead of $M \epsilon$,
replace $\epsilon$ by
$\epsilon/M$
to get
$|\sum_{j=m}^n k_j c_j|
< \epsilon$
for $N(\epsilon/M) < m < n$.

Answer (score 0):

In $\vert \sum\limits c_n k_n \vert \leq \sum\limits \vert c_nk_n\vert \leq M\sum\limits \vert c_n \vert < M\epsilon$ I guess you mean the sums for $n=M,M+1,\dots$, the Cauchy Property.